# What word means what I think "implorements" means?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a title for a section of things I implore people to do. After choosing it, I found that [`Implorements` is not a word](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=implorement). **Is there a word that fits the definition "A list of acts I implore others to do"?**

Comment: You may not find a corresponding noun form for *implore* in contemporary English. (*imploration(s)* is "rare" --ODO http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/imploration ) The alternative would be to chose any suitable synonym of *implore* and use its noun form.

Comment: The things that you implore people to do are your 'pleas'.

Comment: "Petitions", "entreaties", "requests".  "Implorements" is a stretch at best and is apt to garner dumb looks from many who hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think any English speaker would instantly understand *Implorements* when followed by a list of *imploratory* statements to mean exactly what you want.

However, if you feel that *implorements* is just too rare to use there are some alternatives that are slightly more common.

*Beseechings*

> **beseeching**, vbl. n.
>   1. Earnest entreaty, intercession, supplication.
>   2. An earnest request, entreaty, prayer.

---

*Supplications*

> **supplication**, n.
>   The action, or an act, of supplicating; humble or earnest petition or entreaty.

---

<sub>Quoted material from OED</sub>

Comment: _I think any English speaker would instantly understand Implorements._ They'd probably understand 'A good day have' too, but I think other standards of acceptability should be considered. Even the rare but acknowledged word 'implorations' sounds off here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Indeed, English speakers are exceptional at understand 'off' things, they might sound off - but you still know what it means in context, hence the provision for alternatives in answer.  _Implorement_ is attested but it's verb+, but there's nothing stopping it be employed nounally; I don't think it's being overused in it's verb role.

Comment: Accepting because of the point that the word would convey my meaning despite the word's rarity, and for offering some alternatives that work well for my needs.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest *[entreaties](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entreaty)*; that refers rather to your *acts of imploring* than to the acts you implore others to do, but then, if I were to encounter *implorements* I would take it to mean thus also. If you really want a word for the acts you implore others to do, the best I can do is *[agenda](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agenda)* (and I am probably one of the few still using that word consistently as a plural).

Comment: I should have specified this is, indeed, for a list of acts I implore others to do.

Comment: *entreaties* certainly, but an *agendum* suggests far more compulsion than an entreaty or imploration. A single imploration (or plea, or entreaty) toward the entire agenda would though return things from being ordered to being implored.

Answer (score 1):

*[imploration](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imploration)*. It's not a commonly used word today. As a title it might work, especially if the writing is relatively formal, but it might be worth considering if synonyms like *pleas* work better.

Incidentally, it seems that Randle Cotgrave's *A dictionarie of the French and English tongues* of 1611 did indeed use *implorement* in his translation of *requeste*:

[image]
<sub>(source: [pbm.com](http://www.pbm.com/%7Elindahl/cotgrave/817small.gif))</sub>

But it isn't attested otherwise, while *imploration* can be found both earlier and later.

The irony is that it would seem that Cotgrave created *implore* + *ment* rather than use *imploration* which comes from the French *imploration*, and would have been current in both English and French at the time he was writing this French–English dictionary.

Comment: How about "desiderata" ? this is a word that has been used for a list of things for other people to do, without sounding harsh or demanding.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock it could serve there. Stirctly a desideratum is a thing that is desired, and that desire need not be that things are done, but it could certainly serve.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't quite have the urgent/emphatic tone you seem to be after, but I'd actually just use **Requests** as the heading. Unlike the other suggestions, it's a common word that doesn't sound awkward in the plural. If the requests themselves are phrased as "I implore you to...", that should get your point across sufficiently, without needing to resort to non-words in the heading.

Comment: Thanks! As you mention, though, it doesn't carry the same weight. +1 for a common-language option!

Answer (score 0):

'Implorements' isn't a word, and as a neologism is an awkward construction.

When used with a 'possessive' adjective (his/her/their/your/my), **imploring** -or- **implorings** work well --

e.g.:

"My imploring went unheeded."
"Her implorings were to no avail."

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for something similar.
I came across **injunctions**, but it has a bit of a legal tone to it.

The [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/injunction?s=t) definition:

> **injunction** [in-juhngk-shuh n]
>   *noun*
>   1. Law. a judicial process or order requiring the person or persons to whom it is directed to do a particular act or to refrain from doing a particular act.
>   2. an act or instance of enjoining.
>   3. a command; order; admonition:
>    *the injunctions of the Lord.*

Comment: Please add a dictionary definition to support your answer and link to it.